# How to add trailing spaces depending on field length

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to add trailing spaces to each field. My file look like:

Input file:

```
A|B|C|D
```

Field 1 length in output file would be: `1`

Field 2 length in output file would be: `3`

Field 3 length in output file would be: `4`

Field 4 length in output file would be: `6`

Desired output:

```
AB  C   D
```

How to achieve this in shell? Kindly assist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' '{printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' < input > output
```

Would do right space padding and truncation.

Depending on the `awk` implementation, that would be length in terms of bytes or characters (making a difference for multi-byte characters). In any case, not based on the display width of those characters (like for double-width or 0-width characters, or TAB which don't have a display width of 1 on terminals).

Examples:

```
$ echo 'A|B|C|D' | awk -F'|' '{printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}'
AB  C   D
```

(all of those  `A` `B` `C` `D` graphemes are each made of one character, each made of one byte in any locale and each is single-width).

```
$ echo 'A|B|Ç|D' | gawk -F'|' '{printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}'
AB  Ç   D
$ echo 'A|B|Ç|D' | mawk -F'|' '{printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}'
AB  Ç  D
```

(2 byte, 1-width `Ç` character in UTF-8)

```
$ echo $'A|B|C\u0327|D' | gawk -F'|' '{printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}'
AB  Ç  D
$ echo $'A|B|C\u0327|D' | mawk -F'|' '{printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}'
AB  Ç D
```

1-byte, 1-width `C` combined with 0-width, 2 bytes (in UTF-8) combining cedilla to form a 1-width, 2-characters, 3-bytes `Ç` grapheme, the decomposed version of the pre-composed U+00C7 `Ç` character in the previous example.

To take into consideration the display width of characters, with some `expand` implementations (though not GNU `expand`) and assuming the input doesn't contain TAB characters and none of the input fields exceed their allocated width in the first place, you could do:

```
<input sed $'s/|/|\t/g;s/$/|\t/' | expand -t3,8,14,22 | sed 's/| //g' >output
```

Which on the output of `printf '%s\n' 'A|B|C|D' $'A|B|\uc7|D' $'A|B|C\u327|D'` should give:

```
AB  C   D
AB  Ç   D
AB  Ç   D
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Using just `bash` shell functionality...

For the supplied sample data:

```
$ foo="A|B|C|D"; printf "%s%s  %s   %s     \n" $(echo -e "${foo//|/ }" )
AB  C   D     

$ foo="A|B|C\u0327|D"; printf "%s%s  %s   %s     \n" $(echo -e "${foo//|/ }" )
AB  Ç   D
```

For fixed field output per question assuming none of the input fields exceed their maximum specified width:

```
$ foo="A|B|C|D"; printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n" $(echo -e "${foo//|/ }" )
AB  C   D
```

For multibyte characters such as `Ç`, you encounter the issue that the width specifier in `printf` (both `bash` shell builtin and standalone utility) counts bytes, not multibyte characters. Thus you may get "unexpected" output.

```
$ foo="A|B|\uc7|D"; /bin/printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n" $(echo -e  "${foo//|/ }" )
AB  Ç  D    

$ foo="A|B|\uc7|D"; /bin/printf "%-1.1s%-3.3s%-4.4s%-6.6s\n" $(echo -e  "${foo//|/ }" ) | xxd
00000000: 4142 2020 c387 2020 4420 2020 2020 0a    AB  ..  D     .
$
```

Comment: The sample data is all one-char fields, but the question mentions 'depending on field length'. The explicit %s plus specific spaces does not work for variable-length fields -- a width format is necessary..